# Registers and shared memory depending on compiling compute capability?

Tags: cuda, nvcc, gpu-shared-memory

when I compile with `nvcc -arch=sm_13` I get:

```
ptxas info    : Used 29 registers, 28+16 bytes smem, 7200 bytes cmem[0], 8 bytes cmem[1]
```

when I use `nvcc -arch=sm_20` I get:

```
ptxas info    : Used 34 registers, 60 bytes cmem[0], 7200 bytes cmem[2], 4 bytes cmem[16]
```

I thought all the kernel parameters are passed to shared memory but for `sm_20`, it doesn't seem so...?!
Perhaps they are also passed into registers? The head of my function looks like the following:

```
__global__ void func(double *, double , double, int)
```

Thanks so far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In compute capability 2.x devices, arguments to kernels are stored in constant memory. The register difference is probably down to differences in the code generated for math library functions between versions. Are there things like transcendental functions or `sqrt` in the kernel?

Comment: First thanks about the parameters, do you have any source about this? Further: No, no mathematical functions!

Comment: For a reference, it is probably in the ptx guide, but all I can say is "an NVIDIA developer told me it was so". The other possible difference in registers is pointer. Pointers use 1 register on compute 1.x devices, and 2 on Fermi, which is 64 bit internally

Answer (score 4):

As @talonmies states, shared memory differences are due to SM 2.x devices passing kernel arguments via constant rather than shared memory.

However one of the main differences in register usage in SM 2.x devices is the fact that while SM 1.x devices have dedicated address registers for load and store instructions, SM 2.x uses general-purpose registers for addresses.  This tends to increase register pressure on SM 2.x.  Luckily the register file is also 2x larger on GF100 (SM 2.0) vs. GT200 (SM 1.3).

Comment: Mark, while it is true that the register file is double the size on Fermi, the maximum number of registers per thread is also half of sm 1.x devices. The 64 register limit comes into play often in the codes I work with. I know Vasily Volkov has also pointed out the impact of register pressure on the ability of code to achieve high levels of instruction level parallelism on Fermi cards.

Comment: Yes, Fermi increases the maximum threads per SM by 50% (1536/1024), removes address registers, halves the max registers per thread,  doubles the register file size per SM, and slightly increases shared memory access latency.  These all add up to increased sensitivity to resource usage.  Doubling the register file helps, but you are right, it is still tight.  But this is the reality of massively parallel processors.  There are always tradeoffs like this that must be considered when we design a new GPU.  In general though, Fermi is much more architecturally efficient than the Tesla architecture.