# Changing the arch argument in CUDA makes me use more registers

Tags: cuda, nvidia, cpu-registers

I have been writing a kernel on my Tesla K20m, when I compile the software with -Xptas=-v I obtain the following results :

```
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z9searchKMPPciPhiPiS1_' for 'sm_10'
ptxas info    : Used 8 registers, 80 bytes smem, 8 bytes cmem[1]
```

as you can see, only 8 registers are used, however, if I mention the argument -arch=sm_35 the time my kernel executes raises dramatically and the number of registers used too, and I am wondering why

```
nvcc mysoftware.cu -Xptxas=-v -arch=sm_35 
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z9searchKMPPciPhiPiS1_' for 'sm_35'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z9searchKMPPciPhiPiS1_
0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 21 registers, 16 bytes smem, 368 bytes cmem[0]
```

Since in multiple books it was mentioned that using the right architecture for the card was suppose to improve the performances, I wonder why mine are dramatically decreasing.

thanks.

Edit : 
Similar Question and Answer : [Registers and shared memory depending on compiling compute capability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038221/registers-and-shared-memory-depending-on-compiling-compute-capability)

Comment: It looks like the compiler is making different optimization decisions.  Can you provide a short compilable reproducer of what you are seeing?  I'm not as much interested in the change in resource usage as I am in the dramatic slowdown that you are reporting.

Comment: so basically, when i use 'sm_10' the code takes 2.000235 milliseconds to executes but when is use 'sm_35" the code takes 2.538336 to 3.xxxxxx ms which in the case of this kernel is impressive.

Comment: I actually can't give the code at the moment, it uses a part of code which is not mine.

Comment: Could be a compiler bug but withouth the source it is not going to be possible to tell for sure. Try to specify `__launch_bounds__` (try out different values) and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I actually used a defined number of threads and a fixed number of blocks so does that matter to try __launch_bounds__ ?

Comment: The compiler does not use the execution configuration for optimizing the kernel even if it is constant, because one is in host code and the other in device code, so they run through different compilers. So using `__launch_bounds__()` still makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiling with sm_20 and above enables IEEE math and ABI compliance. These two options can increase register count and decrease performance. These two options can be disabled.

Comment: These two are usually a major reason. The compiler is also aware that newer architectures provide more registers and may therefore use them deliberately to increase performance (e.g. use a temporary variable to cache and intermediate result rather than recompute, or schedule loads ahead more aggressively In general I would not recommend turning off either IEEE compliance or the ABI. Use of the ABI in particular enables many of the newer CUDA language features. Programmers should not obsess about register usage unless there is a specific problem with spilling or occupancy.

Comment: Actually I'm not really obsessed with the registers, my problem is the time that increases a lot if I'm compiling using the option -arch=sm_35. @greg would you recommend to disable these options ? or not at all ? or keep compiling my software with -arch=sm_10 since time has a huge importance.

Comment: A similar answer was found here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038221/registers-and-shared-memory-depending-on-compiling-compute-capability

Comment: Try compling with -ftz=true -prec-div=false -prec-sqrt=false. This configures single-precision floating-point math to approximately the same settings as are used by sm_1x compilation. If you are on a 64-bit platform, an additional reason for increased register use can be that for sm_20 and up, 64-bit pointers in device code can be optimized to 32-bit operation only in very limited circumstances, while this optimization can be applied to all device pointers on sm_1x devices, as none of them support more than 4GB of memory.