# Pointless use of CUDA shared memory

Tags: c++, cuda, convolution, gpu-shared-memory

I have two versions of the same algorithm. It was originally the convolution but I modified it to reduce it to this to check where my bottle neck is. Note that there is a single access to global memory per loop:

```
__global__
void convolve (unsigned char * Md, float * Kd, unsigned char * Rd, int width, int height, int kernel_size, int tile_width, int channels){

    int row = blockIdx.y*tile_width + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x*tile_width + threadIdx.x;

    int sum = 0;
    int pixel;
    int local_pixel;
    int working_pixel;

    int row_offset = (kernel_size/2)*(width+kernel_size-1);
    int col_offset = kernel_size/2;

    for(int color=0; color<channels; color++){

        pixel = color*width*height + row*width + col;
        local_pixel = color*(width+kernel_size-1)*(height+kernel_size-1) + row*(width+kernel_size-1) + col + row_offset + col_offset;
        if(row < height  &&  col < width){
            for(int x=(-1)*kernel_size/2; x<=kernel_size/2; x++)
                for(int y=(-1)*kernel_size/2; y<=kernel_size/2; y++){
                    working_pixel = local_pixel + x + y*(width+kernel_size-1);
                    sum += (int)((float)Md[working_pixel]);// * ((float)Kd[x+kernel_size/2 + (y+kernel_size/2)*kernel_size]);

                }
            Rd[pixel] = (int) sum;
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the shared memory version (one single access to shared memory per loop)

```
__global__
void convolve (unsigned char * Md, float * Kd, unsigned char * Rd, int width, int height, int kernel_size, int tile_width, int channels){

    __shared__ unsigned char Mds[256 + 16*4 +4];

    int row = blockIdx.y*tile_width + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x*tile_width + threadIdx.x;

    if(row < height  &&  col < width){

        int sum = 0;
        int pixel;  //the pixel to copy from Md (the input image)
        int local_pixel;    //the pixel in shared memory

        int start_pixel;    //the offset to copy the borders

        int mds_width = tile_width+kernel_size-1;
        int md_width = width+kernel_size-1;
        int md_height = height+kernel_size-1;

        for(int color=0; color<channels; color++){

            pixel = color*md_width*md_height + row*md_width + col  +  (kernel_size/2)*md_width + kernel_size/2; //position (including borders) + offset
            local_pixel = threadIdx.y*mds_width + threadIdx.x  +  (kernel_size/2)*mds_width + kernel_size/2;    //position + offset
  
            //Loading the pixels
            Mds[local_pixel] = Md[pixel];//bringing the central pixel itself (position + offset)

            __syncthreads();

            //Convolving
            for(int x=(-1)*kernel_size/2; x<=kernel_size/2; x++)
                for(int y=(-1)*kernel_size/2; y<=kernel_size/2; y++)
                    sum += (int)((float)Mds[local_pixel + x + y*mds_width]); // * ((float)Kd[x+kernel_size/2 + (y+kernel_size/2)*kernel_size]);
            Rd[color*width*height + row*width + col] = (int) sum;
            sum = 0;

            __syncthreads();

        }
    }
}
```

The launch configuration is

```
convolve<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(Md,Kd,Rd,width,new_height,kernel_size,block_size,colors);

dimGrid = (1376,768)
dimBlock = (16,16)
Md is the read only image
Kd is the filter (3x3)
width = 22016
height = 12288
kernel_size = 3
block_size=16
colors=3
```

I obtain 1249.59 ms with the first algorithm and 1178.2 ms with the second one, which I find ridiculous.
I think that the number of registers should not be a problem. Compiling with ptxas I get:

```
ptxas info: 560 bytes gmem, 52 bytes cmem[14]
ptxas info: Compiling entry function '_Z8convolvePhPfS_iiiii' for 'sm_10'
ptxas info: Used 16 registers, 384 bytes smem, 4 bytes cmem[1]
```

while the info of my device is:

```
Name: GeForce GTX 660 Ti
Minor Compute Capability: 0
Major Compute Capability: 3
Warp Size: 32
Max Treads per Block: 1024
Max Threads Dimension: (1024,1024,64)
Max Grid Size: (2147483647,65535,65535)
Number of SM: 7
Max Threads Per SM: 2048
Regs per Block (SM): 65536
Total global Memory: 2146762752
Shared Memory per Block: 49152
```

Does anyone remotely have any hint about this poor improvement? I don't know anybody else to ask..

EDIT:
I'm using today a different Nvidia card since I cannot access the lab. It also has compute capability 3.0.
I put both if statements out of the loop.
I'm compiling with `-arch compute_30 -code sm_30`
I remove all the castings.
The global matrix is now declared as `const unsigned char * __restrict__ Md`
I used this time a 9x9 filter which makes each pixel be reused 81 times after be brought in shared memory.

I get 3138.41 ms (global version) and 3120.96 ms (shared version) from the terminal.
In the visual profiler it takes longer. This is what I get (screenshots) [link broken].

As lost as I was...

Please find here this algorithm easy to compile and execute:

[link broken]

```
./convolution 8000 4000 159 9 edge_detection_9.txt 0
```

for the global memory version.

```
./convolution 8000 4000 159 9 edge_detection_9.txt 1
```

for the shared memory version.

Comment: My suggestion: Provide a short, complete code.  That is a code that I can copy, paste, compile, and run, without adding anything or changing anything, to see the comparison in execution time.

Comment: This is what the CUDA profiling tools are for. Have a look at nvprof or Nvidia Visual Profiler. Both of these will allow you to identify the performance bottleneck on your kernel. It would not surprise me that this kernel is arithmetic bound. You are performing many operations multiple times in the kernel that could be cached (there is no guarantee that the compiler will optimize this for you).

Comment: As Robert says, we really need a complete reproducing example. I can't be sure from the above, for example, how you are timing the kernel. It may be there is a flaw here? Without being able to reproduce your results it is much harder to help you.

Comment: Please find the file I attached on the last link of the edited post. @Jez

Answer (score 5):

First thing that draw my attention:

```
ptxas info: Compiling entry function '_Z8convolvePhPfS_iiiii' for 'sm_10'
```

Your card has compute capability 3.0 so you should compile with **sm_30**. sm_10 lacked many features of sm_30, had smaller shared memory and less registers.

---

The next thing i would do is to *put the if statement in both kernels outside of the for loop*, for proper kernel comparison.

---

Next, I would **increase the kernel_size to highlight the impact of shared memory**. You have only 9 accesses (*if I counted correctly*) in your kernels and this means the following:

- In the first kernel, you read the elements from global memory directly into registers and use them
- In the second kernel each thread reads one element from global memory and each thread makes 9 accesses in the shared cache.
- Since you don't make heavy reuse of the elements in the shared cache, the price you pay for accessing the global memory is too big.

In addition `sum += (int)((float)Mds[local_pixel + x + y*mds_width]);` generates some bank conflicts into the shared cache decreasing its throughput.

If your kernel_size is always 3, you could also replace the for loops by unrolling them and using fixed indexes, to help the compiler.

---

I'm also concerned about the **penalty of the cast from uchar to float to int**. I know that these operations are costly, further bringing down the shared cache usage gain. Why do you cast for example `(int) sum;` since Rd is unsigned char? Why don't declare Rd as an int* ?

---

I see that Kd is also needed in your kernel. As it is declared now it's stored in the global memory. If it's only a 3x3 filter, you could hardcode it or load it outside of the loop in a thread local variable, that has some chances of being stored into registers.

If that does not work, you could try storing the coefficients into shared memory. Actually replicate the coeffs. there for each thread so that you avoid bank conflicts. The shared memory has 32 ports on Kepler so that will allow extraction of the coefficients symultaneously on all threads in the warp.

---

**In conclusion** I think that your shared cache kernel pays the price of acessing global memory, shared memory bank conflicts, using sm_10 and multiple type casts so that the gain of shared cache is greatly diminished. One general recommendation, use the **CUDA Visual Profiler** to validate these points.

---

Also, I would try using the **texture cache** by declaring **Md** as `const __restrict__` . That could show some speedup compared to global memory access, because that's a multi-ported cache with a special mapping designed to reduce bank conflicts. Actually I expect this to work better even than the shared memory case.

Comment: I didnt even realized about the if statement, you're totally right. Regarding the sm_30 compiling I already tried that and the timing was even worse because of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053339/changing-the-arch-argument-in-cuda-makes-me-use-more-registers.
Regarding the number of times the data inside the shared memory is used I "don't agree". Each thread brings one piece of data to the shared memory but it is used by the rest of them (in most cases 9 times each for a 3x3 kernel). thank you for your help @VAndrei, I'll be back to you

Comment: @Mr.K You can test the shared_cache benefit using the Visual Profiler. My guess is that you have accesses to global memory, conversions and bank conflicts for the shared mem to count too much. Also even if sm_10 gives better time, this has to be fixed as it's not expected behavior. See my revised post.

Comment: You have to be careful with that if statement. Every thread in the block must execute the __syncthreads(), or the kernel behaviour is undefined. This means you cannot have one if statement outside of the loop.

Comment: @Jez Correct me if I'm wrong but if the "else" branch does not do nothing and after it exits, this shouldn't affect the execution. Right?

Comment: @VAndrei: From the [programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#synchronization-functions): `__syncthreads() is allowed in conditional code but only if the conditional evaluates identically across the entire thread block, otherwise the code execution is likely to hang or produce unintended side effects.`

Comment: so, does it mean that __syncthreads() may be waiting for threads that are never reaching that point? I though that if one thread finishes each executions it has no commitment with the others threads of the blocks. Anyways, if I remove that statement the timing is barely affected.

Comment: @VAndrei I edited the post following your advises, unfortunately that's what I get.. I provided the file containing the two kernels.

Comment: I noticed that if I comment the access to Kd (the filter) the timings are quite consistent (shared memory timing is half the global one). But when accessing again to Kd to perform the product it slows down to the same timing than the global one.

Comment: @Mr.K That's obvious. But in your post Kd was already commented so I didn't mention that. Kd is also in the global memory so for each shared mem access you access the global memory ... eliminating the potential gain in your code. So it's solved then? Could you try using const __restrict__ and shared memory?

Comment: no it's not solved since I still need to access Kd. That's exactly what it happens, that access to GM for Kd completely ruins the shared memory potential. What's the alternative? I already tried to allocate Kd in constant memory, shared memory, and restrict (I applied all your advises in the code I provided on the post) but the penalty is still too big.
At this point I may conclude that I cannot benefit from shared memory for the convolution algorithm... @VAndrei

Comment: @Mr.K I see that Kd is a [3x3] filter. You could hardcode the coefficients. If that is not a solution, try and read them outside of the loop in 9 local variables.

Comment: @VAndrei in that concrete example it's a 3x3 filter but it could be even 9x9. And if I compile with -ptxas I can see that the compiler already generates a lot of registers

Comment: @Mr.K You could try storing the coefficients into shared memory. Actually replicate the coeffs there for each thread so that you avoid bank conflicts.

Comment: Well... I kind of ran out of ideas. If I think of something new, I'll post it here.